# How to print ex tax amount on featured, bestseller and related module?

Tags: opencart

How to print ex-tax amount on featured, bestseller and related module? I tried with `$product` array but there is no key for ex-tax amount.

Comment: **1.** What is *ex-tax*? Where it is stored? How it is retrieved? **2.** I don't see any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your bestseller controller file (catalog/controller/module/bestseller.php), and modify this part:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'      => $image,
    'name'       => $result['name'],
    'price'      => $price,
    'special'    => $special,
    'rating'     => $rating,
    'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
);
```

... by declaring 2 new variables, called `price_ex_tax` and `special_ex_tax` in the products array:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'      => $image,
    'name'       => $result['name'],
    'price'      => $price,
    'price_ex_tax' => $this->currency->format($result['price']),
    'special'    => $special,
    'special_ex_tax' => $this->currency->format($result['special'],
    'rating'     => $rating,
    'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
);
```

Then you could access the new variables in the bestseller view file (catalog/view/theme/your_theme_name/template/module/bestseller.tpl). Look for this part:

```
<?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
<div class="price">
  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
  <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

... and replace with:

```
<?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
<div class="price">
  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
  <?php echo $product['price'] . "(" . $product['price_ex_tax'] . ")"; ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price'] . "(" . $product['price_ex_tax'] . ")"; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special'] . "(" . $product['special_ex_tax'] . ")"; ?></span>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You could repeat the same steps for the featured module as well (controller file: catalog/controller/module/featured.php - view file: catalog/view/theme/your_theme_name/template/module/featured.tpl). You can find the related products in the product controller file (catalog/controller/product/product.php), and you can display it in the product view file (catalog/view/theme/your_theme_name/product/product.tpl). I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I added this to the controller file: catalog/controller/module/featured.php

Just above the $this->data['products'][] = array( add the following line:

```
$extax = $this->currency->format($product_info['price']);
```

Then within the array( add:

```
'extax' => $extax,
```

Finally go to catalog/view/theme/your_theme_name/template/module/featured.tpl and add:

`<?php echo $product['extax']; ?>`  where you wish to display the price without tax or

`<?php echo $product['price'] . "(" . $product['extax'] . ")"; ?>` to show both inc and exc, hope that helps.